# Can I use the image of a copyrighted character in my commercial design?

Tags: copyright

I started working on my own designs to sell and had someone come and asked me if I could put a classic Winnie the Pooh image in my design.

I am selling the whole piece to this customer, but can I sell it to them if I put the Winnie the Pooh image on the poster?

I was going to purchase the image on Etsy but I know that it's copyrighted so I'm not sure if I'm able to do that.

Comment: This is a question for a lawyer... but if it were me... **absolutely** not.

Comment: Disney owns Winnie. They have lawyers. Lots of them. That said, people pay for one-off custom things all the time featuring copyrighted characters (such as a mural for one's nursery). Just don't let Disney find out. :)

Comment: Disney owns *their version* of Winnie the Pooh. Methuen owns the [original Shepard drawings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnie-the-Pooh_(book)) and of course, you can draw your own which are bound to be very similar...

Comment: Wait something doesn't add up. Etsy doesn't sell images..? Are you working on some more elaborate collage or something? Buying an artists rendition of Winnie The Pooh off Etsy to then cut/glue/sew into something else? Because you don't buy the rights to a picture on Etsy so not sure you're doing??

Comment: No way I would do that! Legal swamp. I also do see a difference between someone on Etsy selling sew-on-patches with Winnie, and someone _re-selling_ commercially. There is a (at least to me) difference between hommage, fan-art and selling Winnie the Pooh all over again.

Comment: Thank you all for all for getting back to me on this. Just not sure what to do. Maybe I can just order a print and have her pay me what I paid for the print? I wouldn't take credit for it or any extra money from her. As far as Etsy goes, here is what I found and what it said: Set of 4 Classic Winnie the Pooh Quotes - 8x10, INSTANT DOWNLOAD
$10.00 from Etsy - This listing is for four high-resolution, digital images. You will receive the files in vectorized JPEG format. Simply download. It says below that, that it is for personal use and the person selling is not taking credit for any of them.

Comment: copyrights and trademarks of the character images used belong to their respective owners and are not being sold, they are provided to you for free. This item is not a licensed product and I do not claim ownership over the characters used.
It is important to note that copyright restrictions on the characters only permit graphics to be used for one time personal use. Duplicating, copying, or replicating my work in any way is strictly prohibited.

Comment: That user at Etsy could find they are in trouble. Chances are slim they'll be caught, but what they are doing is an infringement of the Disney copyrights, regardless of all their mumbjo jumbo. They are making money off the use of a copyrighted image. It is more amusing that they also try and implement some sort of copyright protection for themselves when they are clearly infringing upon others.

Comment: What you should do is explain to your client that you can not use Disney characters without Disney permission. There's no room for negotiation on that. See here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/how-to-handle-client-requests-to-violate-copyrights

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input and suggestions. Just have to say, I could not figure out how someone could sell a product that is not there's and on a such a big site such as Etsy. I am so confused still on that but I am going to tell my client that I will be unable to make this for them without permission from Disney. Thanks again, you've all been so helpful.

Comment: "vectorized JPEG format" = that's not a thing.

Comment: It sounds like this person is selling their scans of copyrighted material. That is genius if they are getting away with it. Granted, if Disney see it, they might realize it wasn't worth it after their lawyers are done with them.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of very valuable information on the comments, so I summarized them (very shortly) here to keep this question from being marked as unanswered.

Winnie The Pooh is a Disney **copyrighted character**, and as such **can't be used for commercial purposes without acquiring the proper rights** for it. The images available on Etsy that you mention, even if they say they are for personal use, are infringing the law.

Related question:

> [How to handle client requests to violate copyrights?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/how-to-handle-client-requests-to-violate-copyrights)

(mandatory) Note: I am not a lawyer.

Comment: [A.A. Milne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._A._Milne) died in 1956.  But Disney's idea of copyright is the lifetime of Mickey Mouse, plus 70 years.  Sometimes I forget how *important* and *rational* the *law* is...always nice when people retain ownership of things that architect your mind, especially things they didn't create themselves!  ["Life.  Do you want to continue?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFe9wiDfb0E)

Comment: Disney's idea of copyright is "Ours, all ours, forever and ever and ever!"

Comment: Unfortunately it's not only Disney's. Copyright was conceived *to enable creators of intellectual wealth to financially support themselves*, now anything is subject to copyright/patents, from a round-cornered rectangle to [basmati rice](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2001/aug/23/highereducation.biologicalscience).

Answer (score 1):

**Probably not, but maybe, to a limited extent, you can soon.**

**This is specific to the United States of America,** as it's the law  I'm familiar with. If you're doing business in another country, the details about copyright expiration dates and fair use will vary.

This is all as of 2021, but I'll note expected changes in 2022 and 2024.

**As of 2021, *almost* everything Winnie the Pooh related is still protected by copyright.** Is *is* possible to commercially use something protected by someone else's copyright, but if you're just decorating something, probably not.  The details of what you can do are Fair Use law, which is complex, nuanced, and potentially irrelevant if the copyright holder's lawyers have enough money to bankrupt you. To *very* crudely summarize, the closer your work is to non-profit, transformative, academic commentary that uses a small amount of the material and doesn't compete with the original, the more likely it is to be Fair Use. But it's super fuzzy. (And if anyone tells you that "the four factors" represent some sort of easy to interpret test, they don't understand the law in question.)

As background, Winnie the Pooh was created by A. A. Milne, originally in the poem "Teddy Bear" from his collection *When We Were Very Young*, where Pooh is named Edward Bear. Edward was illustrated in that and later books by Ernest Shepard. In the first book of Pooh stories, *Winnie the Pooh*, Milne notes that Christopher Robin has renamed Edward Bear to Winnie-the-Pooh. The relevant publication dates are:

| Source | Copyright Holder(s) | Publication Year | Copyright Expires |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Teddy Bear" (in *When We Were Very Young*) | Milne/Shepard | 1924 | 2020 (Expired!) |
| *Winnie the Pooh* | Milne/Shepard | 1926 | 2022 (Imminent!) |
| *The House at Pooh Corner* | Milne/Shepard | 1928 | 2024 (Soonish) |
| "Winnie the Pooh and the Honey Tree" | Walt Disney Productions | 1966 | 2061 |

Edward Bear originally appears in A.A. Milne's "Teddy Bear" in his poem collection *When We Were Very Young*.  We don't get a lot of description beyond "short and fat." It *does* include illustrations by Ernest Shepard. That entire book is out of copyright in the United States (and, I believe most of the work). That is to say, they're now in the public domain and you can use the text and illustrations as you like. Note that the illustrations in question and black and white line drawings. Any color versions you find were created later and have a later copyright expiration date.

**As of 2021 you are limited to** Milne's 1924 words (so it's Edward Bear, *not* Winnie the Pooh) and Shepard's 1924 black-and-white line drawings (so no color and is distinct from the Disney popularized design).

**As of 2022,** *Winnie the Pooh*'s copyright expires. At that point the words and art in that book will be fair game. Again, no color, and use Shepard's style through 1926, not Disney's later style. But, you can call the bear Winnie the Pooh!

But... Disney has a trademark on the name "Winnie the Pooh." *You can still use it*, but if Disney can successfully convince a court that you've confused customers into thinking you sell Official Disney Winnie the Pooh products, you're doomed. Definitely do *not* title anything you create "Winnie the Pooh"; beyond that, good luck.

**As of 2024** both of Milne's short story collections about Pooh, and the art Shepard provided, will be public domain.

**But Disney's design doesn't expire until at least 2061.** Disney's first Pooh short film is 1966, and in many ways the public idea of Winnie the Pooh is dominated by Disney's interpretation. Disney's Pooh looks similar, but is different. The coloration is, I believe, entirely Disney's creation. If you go anywhere near Disney's design you're at high risk.  That design won't enter the public domain until 2061, and even then you're at risk until Disney's later works all expire.

Some cursory research suggests that Winnie the Pooh's copyright might last a few years longer in Great Britain. The United States copyright durations are longer than many countries; so depending on where you are, it's possibly it's already in the public domain. On the other hand, the United States is trying to get other countries to sign on to longer durations. And it's always possible that the United States will extend its own durations again, but it's practically impossible before 2022 and unlikely to happen by 2024.

(I expect it's much too late for my answer to be useful to the original querent, but as I stumbled across this while researching Pooh copyright expiration dates for myself, I figure it might be useful to others on a similar search.)

Answer (score 0):

You need not to be a lawyer for this, copyright is NOT patent.
You might want to look at [Berne Convention](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/62482/Berne-Convention) and its applicability.

> Berne Convention, Berne also spelled Bern, formally International
>   Convention for the Protection of Literary and Artistic Works, 
>   international copyright agreement adopted by an international
>   conference in Bern (Berne) in 1886 and subsequently modified several
>   times (Berlin, 1908; Rome, 1928; Brussels, 1948; Stockholm, 1967; and
>   Paris, 1971). Signatories of the Convention constitute the Berne
>   Copyright Union.

Comment: Welcome to the community user22557, when answering questions try to elaborate a bit more. When you answer so short, especially without much rep, it gets flagged for review. If you expand on the answer for example how the Berne Convention applies its less likely to be flagged for removal and may even be marked the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The illustrator of the first classic Pooh images holds the copyright for them in the Shepard trust 
I was told. Disney changed the images (Pooh wearing a shirt).  Are you sure Disney 
He all images of Characters- even Shepard’s?

Comment: Welcome! This is more an comment or a new question than an answer ... Can you explain better?