# How do I know the client own the rights to the photos they want me to use?

Tags: images, copyright, legal

I have been given the responsibility of doing a very simple Photoshop edit for a long distance friend's website: putting an image inside of text. They have asked me to use one of their photos to put inside the text.

I'm new to graphic design (not schooled) so I just want to cover my bases. The photo they gave me is really well done, like a professional photographer, except I didn't realize they even did photography. How do I know that the photo they are giving me is their photo that they own the rights to? I don't want to use a photo that's not theirs and get in trouble later on.

I want to provide this service to more people (putting image inside text) but should I just stick to my own images/stock/free for reuse images?

Comment: Are you hosting the site for them?

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/how-to-handle-client-requests-to-violate-copyrights

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cover your bases the only option would be to include it in a contract that the client is responsible for the content and all associated images that may prove an issue and is the one liable by waiving you of all legal issues.

> I want to provide this service to more people (putting image inside
>   text) but should I just stick to my own images/stock/free for reuse
>   images?

Check the terms before doing this because it has been known, depending on where you get your images, there maybe a usage policy you have agreed to.

The answer provided by user3918548 is a viable option but if you are not building time in for "research content purposes" it is not a viable option to search or crawl the web trying to figure out where someone got an image.

Answer (score 2):

When I am not sure if somebody "owns" a photo I use Google image search on the photo. Usually I can find the photographer or original publisher that way or see that the photo is all over the internet.

http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html