# Is recreating other artist's assets a copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright

I have been asked to create some assets for a graphic design app, based on some reference similar assets from the internet.

Note that I have been asked to reproduce all graphics in Photoshop and Illustrator rather than "copy/paste" the originals. As a result the result is not pixel-level accurate, but still resembles the original a lot.

Is this a copyright infringement? (assuming that the original assets)

Comment: At last it depends on the country and its laws for copyright.  Wouldn't it not be better to ask for permission to use the original images?

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: Ask a lawyer, we are designers.*

As mentioned in the [comments](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42768/recreating-similar-assets-and-copytight#comment60211_42769), if you just recreate the outlines or shapes, and the result looks exactly or very similar to the original piece, **you would be infringing copyright because of** **[substantial similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantial_similarity)**.

> To win a claim of copyright infringement in civil or criminal court [US], a
>   plaintiff must show he or she owns a valid copyright, the defendant
>   actually copied the work, and the level of copying amounts to
>   **misappropriation**. Under the doctrine of substantial similarity,
>   a work can be found to infringe copyright even if the wording of text
>   has been changed or visual or audible elements are altered.

Explain to your client what he/she is asking is illegal (and very unethical, by itself and because you are a designer as well). Check this question, you'll find some good ways to deal with this situation:

- [**How to handle client requests to violate copyrights?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/how-to-handle-client-requests-to-violate-copyrights)

Answer (score 0):

Ideas cannot be copyright. You can can be inspired by the idea but make it work for your client. I personally wouldn't copy it but try to include a design aspect from the app that already exists into the icons like color or patterns for example.

Comment: Ideas can't be copyright, but there is such a thing as *substantial similarity* that can cause litigation problems. There is also *trade dress*, which may prevent use of a look-alike design, especially if it looks like an established competitor's brand.

Comment: Correct which is why you should always use ideas soley as inspiration. If you design anything it should speak specifically to that brand.